# what does it mean: '=' : left operand must be l-value?

Tags: c, struct

i'm writing a code using structures that will read a text file with data about book. name, author, publisher, genre ect...

my header file looks like:

```
typedef struct book{    

    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char authors[AUTHORS_NAME_LENGTH];
    char publisher[PUBLISHER_NAME_LENGTH];
    char genre[GENRE_LENGTH];
    int year;
    int num_pages;
    int copies;
}book;


typedef struct library
{    

    book books[BOOK_NUM];

}library;

typedef char* string;
```

the code is:

```
    if (NULL == (incoming_books = fopen(".\books.txt", "r")))
    {            /* opening file for reading */
        /*printf("Error opening file"); write to file*/
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(incoming_books))
    {
        fgets(line,200,incoming_books);//copies one line, assuming no longer than 200 chars

        idx_helper = strchr(line, '$');//finds '$' index, attribures are seperated by "$$$"
        index = (int)(idx_helper - line);// cast index into int
        char_num = index;
        if (NULL != memcpy(temp_string, line, char_num))//copies string (name)
            temp_book->name = *temp_string;

        index += 3;                         // incrementing index by 3
        idx_helper = strchr(&line[index], '$');   // same for authors
        index = (int)(idx_helper - &line[index]);
        char_num = index;
        if (NULL != memcpy(temp_string, &line[index], char_num*sizeof(char)))
        temp_book->authors = *temp_string;
    }
```

and so on for each book attribute

i am getting two errors:
1. Error    7   error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value 
   which points to the lines temp_book->name = *temp_string; and temp_book->authors = *temp_string;
2. IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
    which points for same lines.

could it be a pointer problem?

Comment: Tip: use yoda conditions don't, natural won't find it human readers.

Answer (score 1):

Because arrays are non-modifiable *lvalue*s.

Excerpt from the [C11 Standard Draft N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) — (*bold segments were highlighted in this answer to help the reader find the interesting part*).

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
>
> 1. An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than `void`) that potentially designates an object; <sup>64)</sup> if an *lvalue* does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the *lvalue* used to designate the object. **A modifiable *lvalue* is an *lvalue* that does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>64)</sup><sub>The name ‘‘*lvalue*’’ comes originally from the assignment expression E1 = E2, in which the left operand E1 is required to be a (**modifiable**) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an
>   object ‘‘locator value’’. What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described as the ‘‘value of an expression’’.</sub>

You use `memcpy()` to copy to the `temp_string`, you should use it to copy to the array directly instead. Also, don't use `sizeof(char)` as it will never be anything but *1* and always allocate space for the `nul` terminator, and copy the `nul` terminator. Otherwise when you pass the array to a function that expects a *string* like the various `str`* functions or `printf()` with the `"%s"` specifier *undefined behavior* will occur.

Aditionally, in your code there is this

```
while (!feof(incoming_books))
```

this will only be *true* when `fgets()` fails, then it will happen after the first time `fgets()` failed and as you never check that the last line will be repeated, you should instead do this

```
while (fgets(line, 200, incoming_books) != NULL)
```

Comment: Oh, of course, arrays aren't assignable -- but the connection with lvalues is more complex, as you've now included in the answer. That will make for a nice point of reference in the future :-)

Comment: I think GCC says the right thing: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FV6kDIyHbb0kOgwv or https://ideone.com/WoBswo . I think the OP is using MSVC.